# Select elements by attributes with ":" (colon)

Tags: javascript, css, attributes

In my project, there's a case where a library generates elements, and  I need to select specific elements from there - which happen to contain an attribute with ":".
In other words, I ended up attempting to select using: `document.querySelectorAll("[xml:space]")`.
But, when tested in Chrome, it didn't work, nor selecting using `document.querySelectorAll("['xml:space']")` - they both threw a `DOMException`:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHIeB.png

My question is, how to make the above selector return the list of the elements with `xml:space` attribute?
Thanks!

Comment: I think you need to escape the colon `'[xml\\3A space]'` see https://mothereff.in/css-escapes

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to escape the colon

```
document.querySelectorAll('[xml\\3A space]')
```

I used https://mothereff.in/css-escapes to get the code above :)

Answer (score 23):

Escape the `:` by preceding it with a double backslash `\\`

```
document.querySelectorAll("[xml\\:space]")
```

See this:

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=883044

Comment: Not sure why this answer is linking to a Bugzilla report that has been rightfully closed as not a bug.

Answer (score 3):

A more robust solution than only targeting colons specifically would be to use [`CSS.escape()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS/escape)

```js
const query = CSS.escape("xml:space")    // "xml\\:space"
document.querySelectorAll(`[${query}]`)
```

Note that we keep the square brackets outside of `CSS.escape()` as those are not part of the attribute name and we want them to keep their semantic meaning in this selector.

Answer (score -1):

can also do

```
document.querySelectorAll('[id="xml:space"]')
```

Comment: Best option for when the id is dynamic.

Comment: This is completely wrong and inapplicable: the question was about an attribute with the name `xml:space`, *not* an ID attribute with the value `xml:space`.