# How does Vue.js select `v-on:click` selector?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to replicate Vue.js just for learning purposes.

In very basic terms I can do this:

```
<button v-on-click="reverseMessage">Reverse Message</button>
```

```javascript
var element = document.querySelectorAll('[v-on-click]')[0]
```

But, I'm interested to know how they select `v-on:click`.

When I try `document.querySelectorAll('[v-on:click]')` I get this error:

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Document': '[v-on:click]' is not a valid selector.

Comment: Inspect your element and look what is generated. You can also use Vue.js Chrome extension. The fact is that events are registered and you won't see any v-on:click after vue.js render the root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [repository on Github for Vue](https://github.com/vuejs/vue), it looks like they first get all of the attributes for an element. Then they test a regex `const onRE = /^@|^v-on:/` against each attribute, and if it matches, they remove the `v-on:` or `@` prefix from the attribute name (via `name.replace(onRE, '')`) leaving the name of the event to handle. Then they handle the event.

Here's a simplified example of their method:

```js
const vonReg = /^@|^v-on:/;
let attributes = document.getElementById("foo").attributes;

let names = [];
for (let i = 0; i < attributes.length; i++) {
  names.push(attributes[i].nodeName);
}

names.forEach((name) => {
  if (vonReg.test(name)) {
    let eventName = name.replace(vonReg, '');
    console.log('We need to handle this event: ' + eventName);
  }
})
```

```html
<div id="foo" v-on:click="test"></div>
```

---

If you want to use `querySelectorAll`, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45110893/select-elements-by-attributes-with-colon) explains that you need to escape the colon. In your case it would look like this:

```
document.querySelectorAll('[v-on\\3A click]')
```